# how to run virtualenv python on mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, virtualenv

I am trying to use virtualenv to create a virtual python environment on my mac. I have downloaded virtualenv however I can't run it because it can't find the path to my installation of python3 even though I am supplying the correct path. Here is the command I have run and the response:

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python3 newfolder
zsh: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6: no such file or directory
```

Also I have tried running the command with quotes like so:

```
virtualenv --python='/usr/local/bin/python3' newfolder
zsh: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6: no such file or directory
```

Please note I am supplying the correct path to python3 as far as I can tell.
Here is what I get when I run `which python3`

```
which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Also virtualenv appears to be correctly installed. Here is evidence for this:

```
pip3 install virtualenv
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /Users/mathewlewis/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (16.7.9)
```

Also, in case this is relevant, the software I have is currently `mac os catalina 10.15.2`

Not only would I like a solution (as has been given at this point) I would also like a reason why this didn't work.

Comment: This is very suspect. Your `pip3` is associated with a Python 3.7 instance, but your `python3` is associated with a Python 3.6 instance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try:

```sh
python3 -m venv venv
source ./venv/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `virtualenv` script [uses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) bad interpreter `/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.6` which you have had installed and later removed. To fix the script reinstall `virtualenv` package using an existing Python:

```
pip3 install -U virtualenv
```