# Why PythonTeX is running the 2.x version if I have the 3.x python version in my Mac?

Tags: python, latex

When running the command `pythontex` in the terminal, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/TeX/texbin/pythontex", line 50, in <module>
    import pythontex2 as pythontex
  File "/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/scripts/pythontex/pythontex2.py", line 61, in <module>
    from pygments.styles import get_all_styles
ImportError: No module named pygments.styles
```

The are two reasons why this confuses me:

- Why is it running the `pythontex2` if I have the Python 3.7 version as the main one;
- why can't he find the module `pygments`?

I'm using a MacBook with M1, if this is useful.

Thank you ind advance.

Comment: use `python3` to execute it instead of `python`.

Comment: use a [virtualenv set to python3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59637985/9267296) to ensure you are always running in the correct context. This is something you should **ALWAYS** do...

Answer (score -1):

You have to install Pygments. Use:

```
$ pip install pygments
```

in your environment.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Did you make sure to [read the question carefully?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) They appear to be using a version of `pythontex` that is part of a texlive distribution, and are confused about why a different version of Python is running. They likely need help with configuration unique to texlive.